# Transliteration; legibility; is “ethno-centrism” present; can avoidance be codified?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation, editing, languages

1. I only mean “ethno” as “any subgroup of humans”, almost like “anthro” could refer to “the group of all humans” - not specifically contemporary connotations of ‘ethnicity’ as affiliated with *race*, for example.
2. “Centrism” is a loosely conjectured notion that the subjective, discursive, humanistic aspects of regulatory policy are in part influenced by a human sub-group, perhaps one that is more prevalent, in a given context

The reason why I ask is not to defend the following question: [Are old languages more expressive for emotions?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46995/are-old-languages-more-expressive-for-emotions)

but only to use it as an example that triggered an unrelated thought -

I wanted to transliterate the Farsi script, for my own, and any others’, benefit as to being able to read it better. I hesitated when I realized that I would never do that for any other languages or scripts I can read.

Should we conclude with a codified rule - we never transliterate languages as editorial policy, unless the author chooses to?

Or, as English is (I think) the “official language” of the site (is it?), does it enhance site quality to always allow the editing of non-English with, say, IPA pronunciations in parentheses, or a given transliteration system (ie, Wade-Giles, or Pinyin, for Chinese) - or even a definition via a site-wide format, like they do in Wikipedia / Wiktionary articles?

---

> فارسی
>
> Language
>
> Persian
>
> Fârsi
>
> Alternative forms
>
> پارسی‎ (pârsi)
>
> Etymology
>
> From Arabic فَارْسِي‎ (fārsī), from Early New Persian پارسی‎ (pârsi,
> “Persian, Persic”).
>
> Pronunciation
>
> (Classical Persian) IPA(key): /fɑːɾˈsiː/ (Dari Persian) IPA(key):
> /fɑːɾˈsiː/ (Iranian Persian) IPA(key): /fɒːɾˈsiː/ (Tajik) IPA(key):
> /fɔɾˈsi/
>
> Adjective
>
> فارسی • (fârsi)
>
> Persian, Persic ‏توی شیراز یه فرش فارسی خریدم.‎‎ tu-ye širâz ye farš-e
> fârsi xaridam. I bought a Persian rug in Shiraz.
>
> Persian (the language of Ancient Persia). Persian (the language of modern Iran).

[https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/فارسی](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C)

> Persian (/ˈpɜːrʒən, -ʃən/), also known by its endonym Farsi (فارسی, Fārsī, [fɒːɾˈsiː])

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it all depends on context. If someone asks a question about cognates of a particular Greek word, and they write the word in Greek in their question, then I won't bother transliterating other Greek words in my answer—but I will transliterate (say) Sanskrit, since the asker has shown no indication that they know Devanagari. The descendants of a PIE root might be written in a dozen or more different scripts and few historical linguists are fluent in all of them.

Since this site is in English, we can as a rule assume that everyone using it is familiar with the Latin alphabet. (This might be "ethnocentric" but it's not something that can be avoided. The sort of discussion that this site is built around cannot function without a common language.) When talking about individual words written in any other script, I would provide a transliteration, unless the question makes it clear that a transliteration isn't necessary—both for the original asker and for anyone else who might find the question useful in the future. (If you're asking about the relationship between a particular Sanskrit word and a Hindi descendant, that question is unlikely to be useful to anyone who doesn't know Devanagari.)

When *using* rather than *mentioning* those words, on the other hand (e.g. quoting a grammarian who didn't write in English), I would just provide a translation rather than transliterating anything. Someone who knows (e.g.) Greek well enough to read it in the original language won't need a transliteration. Someone who *doesn't* know Greek will find the original text just as incomprehensible no matter what script it's written in: a translation is far more useful.

Answer (score 1):

In specialized linguistic venues, for example a journal of Chinese Stylistics, there may be an expectation that all readers can read Chinese, so no requirement for transliteration. Otherwise, and unless the topic of discussion is the writing system, in a linguistic journal you would transliterate written data into some standardized Latin-based system. A competing convention existed in the Soviet Union to use Cyrillic phonetic transcriptions, I don't know what current practice is.

Keeping with the theme that Linguistics SE is a general-purpose English-language site for asking questions about linguistics and is not a specific-language site, the appropriate behavior would be to employ a Latin-based transcription for data (except when the issue is about writing). Of course, that's a suggestion and not a hard rule. It would not be totally inappropriate to supplement a question or answer with a standard transliteration, *provided* that this can be done without imputing to the author a claim that they did not make (for example, your understanding of "correct transliteration" might be in error). It is better to comment on the transliteration question, and leave it to the author to edit their answer.